# Swift Static Variables reach with dynamic parameters

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to use static variables for `APIrequests`. This API runs with `Get Method` and I have to run with some parameters with dynamically. So How can I change this parameters ?

For Example :

```
static let productDetail = "http:.../ProductDetail?productID=101&subNo=148"
```

I want to reach with `XClass.productDetail` also change `productID=101` and `subNo=148` with needed parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it a function and then pass the `productID` and `subNo` you want as parameters:

```
static func productDetail(productID: Int, subNo: Int) -> String {
    return "http:.../ProductDetail?productID=\(productID)&subNo=\(subNo)"
}
```

If you have more parameters, you could also pass them as dictionary:

```
func productDetail(parameters: [String: String]) -> String {
    var str = "http:.../ProductDetail?"
    parameters.forEach {
        str.append("\($0.key)=\($0.value)&")
    }
    str = String(str.dropLast()) // drops last '&' char
    return str
}
```

Usage:

```
productDetail(parameters: ["productID": "108", "subNo": "93"])
// returns "http:.../ProductDetail?productID=108&subNo=93"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does it solve with get set parameters ?

Comment: No it won't, it's a function. What are you trying to do? Do you want to update the url as well?

Comment: I just ask a question. I want to update url like your answer. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, if you do want to change the url as well, you could add it as parameter and then insert it in place of `str`. Or, you make a separate function for each url, named by what it is: such as `productDetail`, or `accountDetail`. Then, you'll always know which url you're calling.